# Mouse pointer lag on Ubuntu 16.10 correlated with use of graphics card

Tags: nvidia, graphics, mouse, touchpad

I am having problems with laggy mouse pointer movement in Ubuntu 16.10. The problem only occures after graphic intensive activities such as playing 1080p videos, browsing high-res images or playing games. When it appears, it persists until I reboot my computer, even logging off and on doesn't help. Also, the problem only appears when I am using integrated touchpad of my notebook - when I connect a USB mouse the pointer moves as usual (but it still lags when I try to use touchpad). I am using NVIDIA GeForce 940MX card with NVIDIA binary driver 367.57.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. At first I rebooted my computer and entered the BIOS settings using F2 key. Then I changed the Touchpad settings from Advanced to Basic.

Please note that this solution is likely to be hardware-specific - I am using Acer Aspire E 15. You can also check out [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2337414) on Ubuntu Forums where I've found it.